# .cvs export of sharepoint list removes leading zero's

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, excel, export-to-excel

My site includes functionality that exports a list as a .csv file. I can't change the fact that the list is being exported as a .csv.

The problem is that when the list is exported, the leading zeros get automatically removed from one of the numeric columns.

Does anyone know a way to STOP this from happening BEFORE the list is exported? AKA Changing excel settings does not satisfy the customer and I need code that I can add to the existing export functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to interfere with the **Export to Excel** function.

Is this a **Number** column you have in your list? Per my test, no leading zero will be allowed in a numeric value, which is the rule for both SharePoint list and Excel. You can only have leading zero if you are using a **Text** column.

You can change the column type to **Text** and then try exporting again. The exported csv file will keep the number column as the type of **General**, and the text column as the type of **Text** in Excel.

Comment: The column is already a text column in the SP list because sometimes the numbers end with a letter. For example, 0005482A. It is still cutting off leading zeroes, even as a text column :/

Comment: @Torybee Well that’s unusual. I have tested a few times and I cannot produce this one. What is the version of SharePoint and Office client you are using? Maybe try testing in another column or another list and see if you have the same problem.